# How to make cursor unchanged in margin area of CSS

Tags: html, css, margin, mouse-cursor

I have a div with `width=160px`, `height=80px`. For some reason the div has a `margin-left=540px`. Also, in CSS, I set `cursor:pointer`.

The problem is, when I move the cursor the the left of the div, the margin area, the mouse change to pointer.

How can I let the cursor unchange when I move it to the margin area, and only change when I move it on the div?

I need to use margin, because using position will cause the some structure bug.

Comment: Do you mean to have the cursor state `cursor: default` when it's over the margin-area of the `<div>`?

Comment: When hovering the margin area of a `<div>`, [the cursor change is by default not applied to the margin area](http://jsfiddle.net/gLNnw/).

Comment: And could you use padding instead of margin?

Answer (score 4):

May you can achieve this with css `:after` `pseudo` element like this:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  margin-left: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: -100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Original fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/EwLVu/

Answer (score 0):

Could you use nested divs?
Apply a padding to the outer div to simulate a margin, then apply the cursor setting to the inner div.

Here's an example:

```css
.outer {
  padding-left: 50px;
  border: solid black 1px;
}

.inner {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid red 1px;
}

.clearFloat {
  clear: Both;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner">inner content<br />More inner content</div>
</div>
<div class="clearFloat"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I found a solution.
I had in my css writen something like thaht:

```
body {cursor:url('adress to your .cur file'), default;}
```

With this code when my cursor was over an area of margin, the cursor happen to be default.
What I did was to change the location of the cursor code, I change it from BODY direct to HTML and here it is:

```
html {cursor:url('adress to your .cur file'), default;}
```

and now works great.